# Running out of memory using Node.js to optimise route pairings with mongodb database

Tags: javascript, algorithm, node.js, optimization

Ive been trying to crack this for days, any help would be **GREATLY** appreciated.  Basically im trying to iterate through this array of destination pairings and see if the overall distance can be improved by recalculating the mileage on each "inverted" pair.  If the total mileage for the inverted pair is better than the original, I replace the original pairs with their inverted versions.

The Problem im finding is that I either run out of memory is I leave this process running, or the results aren't optimized in the way I expect ( i gain mileage).

I appreciate, I'm being a little sketchy here but im not sure where im going wrong. To put it into a constructive question: Can anyone help create a function/algorithm in JavaScript that can iterate through an array of pairings and optimise the same? ...please?

```
var firstResult = [{"from":"DE55 7RA","to":"DE55 4XJ","oNum":"3740003654","dNum":"3650645273","metres":"536"},{"from":"WF2 0XF","to":"WF2 0XE","oNum":"3740003632","dNum":"3650645256","metres":"304"},{"from":"WF9 2RH","to":"WF9 3AP","oNum":"3740003657","dNum":"3650645279","metres":"4132"},{"from":"LS10 1BG","to":"LS9 8HY","oNum":"3740003637","dNum":"3650645266","metres":"2941"},{"from":"WF10 5UA","to":"WF8 4QD","oNum":"3740003646","dNum":13,"metres":"7248"},{"from":"HD2 1UA","to":"WF15 6JL","oNum":"3740003641","dNum":"3650645270","metres":"6745"},{"from":"HU14 3HJ","to":"HU15 2PE","oNum":"3740003640","dNum":"3650645259","metres":"13309"},{"from":"WF2 0XF","to":"WF5 8NE","oNum":"3740003631","dNum":"3650645262","metres":"9862"},{"from":"WF9 2XX","to":"WF8 4QD","oNum":"3740003656","dNum":83,"metres":"13705"},{"from":"WF9 2XX","to":"WF8 4QD","oNum":"3740003647","dNum":67,"metres":"13705"},{"from":"WF9 2XR","to":"WF8 4QD","oNum":"3740003636","dNum":59,"metres":"13545"},{"from":"DN14 6XL","to":"DN14 0SB","oNum":"3740003642","dNum":"3650645268","metres":"20763"},{"from":"NG16 4HY","to":"NG15 0DR","oNum":"3740003635","dNum":"3650645258","metres":"13165"},{"from":"DN6 7FB","to":"S73 0UN","oNum":"3740003639","dNum":"3650645255","metres":"18835"},{"from":"LS25 6JH","to":"WF6 1GX","oNum":"3740003652","dNum":"3650645253","metres":"22861"},{"from":"DN3 3FF","to":"DN9 1LB","oNum":"3740003660","dNum":"3650645264","metres":"21343"},{"from":"DN6 7FB","to":"S71 3HQ","oNum":"3740003638","dNum":"3650645278","metres":"19268"},{"from":"S43 4UX","to":"S6 1LY","oNum":"3740003633","dNum":"3650645276","metres":"30365"},{"from":"S43 4UX","to":"S6 1LY","oNum":"3740003651","dNum":"3650645275","metres":"30365"},{"from":"DN14 6XL","to":"HU3 4UW","oNum":"3740003667","dNum":"3650645277","metres":"41502"},{"from":"LS25 6JH","to":"LS7 1PZ","oNum":"3740003653","dNum":"3650645274","metres":"25194"},{"from":"LS25 6JH","to":"BD4 0SG","oNum":"3740003658","dNum":"3650645269","metres":"43788"},{"from":"DN14 6XL","to":"HU7 0XS","oNum":"3740003648","dNum":"3650645265","metres":"49066"},{"from":"NG90 1BS","to":"DE6 1EX","oNum":"3740003643","dNum":"3650645261","metres":"44283"},{"from":"S80 3YY","to":"HD6 1LJ","oNum":"3740003665","dNum":"3650645260","metres":"80026"},{"from":"S80 2RZ","to":"BD8 9HQ","oNum":"3740003634","dNum":"3650645263","metres":"95649"},{"from":"NG90 1BS","to":"HU7 0YW","oNum":"3740003650","dNum":"3650645272","metres":"156190"},{"from":"NG90 1BS","to":"HU12 8TB","oNum":"3740003644","dNum":"3650645267","metres":"160285"},{"from":"NG90 1BS","to":"YO17 6YA","oNum":"3740003645","dNum":"3650645257","metres":"172388"},{"from":"NG90 1BS","to":"YO17 9HG","oNum":"3740003649","dNum":"3650645271","metres":"176868"}],
    fs = require('fs'),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    logPostals = fs.createWriteStream('postals.txt', {'flags' : 'w'}),
    db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/legs');

var Leg = new Schema({
      from: {
        type: String,
        validate: /^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$/i,
        trim: true
      },
      to: {
        type: String,
        validate: /^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$/i,
        trim: true
      },

      time: Number,
      distance: Number
    })

var legModel = mongoose.model('Leg', Leg);

var legIndex = 0, armIndex= 0 , inverted = 0, original = 0;
var goCompare = function(){
   _.each(firstResult , function(leg){
     _.each(firstResult , function(arm){
      if(leg.from !== arm.from){
              legModel.find({
              from: leg.from,
              to: arm.to
            }, function(err, data) {      
              if (data.length > 0) {
                legModel.find({
                  from: arm.from,
                  to : leg.to
                },function(e,d){
                   inverted = data[0].distance +  d[0].distance;
                   original = (leg.metres*1) + (arm.metres*1) ;
                   if( original  >  inverted ){
                   legIndex = firstResult.indexOf(leg);
                   armIndex = firstResult.indexOf(arm);

                  firstResult[legIndex] ={
                    from : leg.from,
                    to : arm.to,
                    metres : data[0].distance,
                    oNum : leg.oNum,
                    dNum : arm.dNum
                   };
                   firstResult[armIndex] = {
                    from : arm.from,
                    to : leg.to,
                    metres : d[0].distance,
                    oNum : arm.oNum,
                    dNum : leg.dNum
                   };

                   _.each(firstResult , function( item ){
                      logPostals.write(item.from +'\t'+ item.to +'\t'+item.metres +'\r\n')
                   })

                  goCompare();
                 }else{

                 }//end of if distance comparison
                })//end of function callback from search
              }//end of if data...
            }//end of err...data
        )//end of find
      }
    })
  })
}//end of go compare###############
goCompare();
```

Comment: Hi, I don't mind having a hack at this, but I just noticed this is from October in 2012, how did you end up solving this?

Comment: I did figure something out...let me have a dig around and I'll post the code :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting large Javascript objects when process is running out of memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111472/deleting-large-javascript-objects-when-process-is-running-out-of-memory)